# Adding duplicate labels within polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, duplication

Is there a way to include multiple duplicates of the same label within a single polygon in QGIS?

So a single polygon(s) with a label from a single field, repeated at a set distance within the polygon - shown in the image as made by ArcMap Maplex engine.

[image: labels within a polygon]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the `Layer Properties > Symbology` and set the Symbol by `Fill > Point Pattern Fill > Marker > Font Marker`.

Then scroll down to find *Data Defined Override* (small dropdown icon) next to the **Character(s)**, and select your field to display as the label.

Distance, displacement, offsets can be adjusted by selecting `Point Pattern Fill`.

[image]

Comment: Great, that seems to work nicely. Thanks.